# jquery array of checkboxes and [NaN]

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#div_box_submit_ad").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var checked = []
        var hidden_d = $("#hidden_d").val();
        var hidden_id_ad = $("#hidden_id_ad").val();
        $("input[name='chk[]']:checked").each(function ()
        {
            checked.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
            console.log(checked);
            alert(checked);
            alert(hidden_d);
            alert(hidden_id_ad);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

It works fine but my problem is that when the checkboxes contain text instead of number, in the alert() function i get this: [NaN]..

How to avoid this? I need to avoid this also because i need to pass the array to a php function in the next step..

Comment: How would you like it to be avoided? what value are you expecting when you value is a non numerical text?

Comment: sorry for my question but I found myself the error.. I just changed this line:

checked.push(parseInt($(this).val()));

to

checked.push($(this).val());

and now it's fine :-)

Comment: why do you have text values if you want them to be numbers? Issue doesn't make sense

Comment: you gave my the right input telling me that some values are not numeric..

Comment: sorry I used that function for an i don't know why reason.. I simply have multiple checkboxes with some values that are numbers and some values that are text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this line to:

```
checked.push(parseInt($(this).val()) || 0);
```

Which instead of pushing `NaN`to the array it will push `0` - you may want to change this value to `null` or other

Otherwise you can also add a `if` statement to check before populating the array

```
var myInteger = parseInt($(this).val());
if(myInteger >= 0) {
   checked.push(myInteger);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i just realized that the parseInt function wasn't need for my purpose.. thanks :-)

Comment: @P.Davide thanks is nice, but an upvote is probably what you meant ;)